# How to make zip file using Maven ANT script?

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, ant

Please review this code and tell me How to make zip(MercedesBenz.zip) under this location D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz, that zip should contain target folder and few files?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<target name="MercedesBenz-Build">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" dir="C:/ApacheMaven/Project/MercedesBenz">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="mvn" />
        <arg value="clean" />
        <arg value="install" />
    </exec>

    <copy todir="D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz/target" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="C:/ApacheMaven/Project/MercedesBenz/target">
          <include name="*.war"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>         
    <echo message="Docker war created successfully" />
</target>
<target name="zip">
    <zip destfile="D:/docker/MercedesBenz.zip"
        basedir="D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz"
        includes="D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz/**/*.*">
    </zip>
</target>

<target name="end-to-end-setup" depends="MercedesBenz-Build, zip"/>
```

It giving Warning as below

```
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [INFO] Total time: 2.820 s
 [exec] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-02T10:48:40+05:30
 [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/163M
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\docker\uat\MercedesBenz\target
 [echo] Docker war created successfully
```

**zip:
      [zip] Warning: skipping zip archive D:\docker\MercedesBenz.zip because no files were included.**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the image with text.  Never post text, code, or error messages as an image; it's not searchable or copyable as text.

Comment: Can you verify for us the list of files that actually exist in `D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz/`? Also, make sure you are not relying on the order of the list in the `depends` attribute to strictly dictate the order in which your targets actually run. If `MercedesBenz-Build` *needs* to run before `zip`, set `MercedesBenz-Build` as a depends target for `zip` itself.

Comment: D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz/ this folder contains, two .yml files and one File and one target folder with .war file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<target name="zip">
    <zip destfile="D:/docker/MercedesBenz.zip"
        basedir="D:/docker/${instance}/MercedesBenz"
        includes="**/**">
    </zip>
</target>
```